# React Material UI Grid Item - how to make List component take fullwidth of Grid container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a List inside a Grid item with `xs={12}`, but I cannot figure out how to get the ListItems to spread across the entire width of the List's div. The list's secondaryAction button appears at the end of the div, but all the ListItems are densely packed on the left side.

```js
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <List sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
    {theList.map((item, id) => (
      <ListItem key={id} secondaryAction={<Button>Open</Button>}>
        <Accordion>
          <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
            <Typography>{item.name}</Typography>
            <Typography>{item.address}</Typography>
            <Typography>{item.phone}</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
        </Accordion>
      </ListItem>
    ))}
  </List>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is the grid item inside a grid container? Does the container have a width? I can't reproduce your issue. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-monad-vg7nl?file=/pages/index.js) with a working example of ListItems taking up full width